# Fastest way to convert raster to dataframe (with xy data)

Tags: r, dataframe, raster, r-sp

I'm looking for the most efficient way to convert any `Raster*` object into a `data.frame` while preserving the `xy` data.

```
library(raster)
library(sp) 

# Read in our raster stack 
s <- readRDS(gzcon(url("http://web.pdx.edu/~porlando/stack.RDS")))

# Converting to data.frame takes ~6 minutes! 
df <- as.data.frame(s, xy = T, na.rm = T)
```